# Find the sum of count of the numbers in which array elements are divided

Tags: arrays, data-structures

Given an array of N positive integers and a number K where K is used as a threshold value to divide each element of the array into sum of different numbers. Find the sum of count of the numbers in which array elements are divided.

Input: N = 4, K = 3 Arr[] = {5, 8, 10, 13}
Expected Output: 14

```
def totalCount(self, arr, n, k):  

for i in range(0, n):
    if (arr[i]%k==0) and (count = arr[i]/k):
      return 1
count1 = arr[i]/k+1

sum = count + count1
return sum
```

Comment: Where is your input data? and provide an expected output!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you must show us what you have tried so far, add some code and some input with expected output.

Comment: Input:
N = 4, K = 3
Arr[] = {5, 8, 10, 13}
Output: 14

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also don't know the answer and as I am searing for it I encounter this and the explanation for the above is

```
N = 4, K = 3
a[] = {5, 8, 10, 13}
Output: 14
```

Explanation: Each number can be expressed as sum of different numbers less than or equal to K as :

`5 (3 + 2), 8 (3 + 3 + 2), 10 (3 + 3 + 3 + 1), 13 (3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 1)`

So, the sum of count of each element is (2+3+4+5)=14.

Comment: At least this explains the question